# How to sync multiple Client's apps with restful webservice?

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, web-services

I'm working on a project that involves about 5 Android clients viewing a list of items and taking ownership of these items. Everything is loaded through a RESTful Java web service, and data is stored in a mysql server.

A list of items is loaded to the app, containing ITEM-NAME and OWNER.
When one selects an item, all other clients should update to show that such item is now owned by them.

Every time an item is selected, a request is sent to the a synchronous block in the web service and this client takes ownership of the item - after verifying that noone else has taken it before him.

My question now is: what are the best practices to update this newly selected item to all the clients, as to not reload the whole list unnecessarily every n seconds?

The way I'm thinking is:
Every time an update happens, a datetime will be stored on mysql.
Android apps will check every 5 or so seconds for this value. If it's the same as the one stored on a local variable, nothing happens. If it's different, the whole list is reloaded and the local variable is updated.

Would this suffice?

I'd also like to note that the list wont be too extensive, so no need to update an specific item separately; the whole list being reloaded wouldnt be too heavy a load.

Sorry if this type of question is not for stack overflow, but idk where else to post it. If it doesnt fit, please guide me in this regard.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally frequent, short polling is a bad idea. All requests will impact client's and server's performance and bandwidth. Depending on your use case almost none request will result with no changes.

A better approach is to let the server notify the clients about changes. 
This is most commonly done using [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging). Using FCM your server can notify all known clients whenever a change occured.

Alternatively client could use "long polling": Client sends a HTTP request, but server does not respond until a change occurs.

Also WebSockets could be an option -- but it might not fit well in your REST architecture.

#### Short Polling

```
t01: Client: Hi Server, is there an update?
t02: Server: No
t03: Client: Hi Server, is there an update?
t04: Server: No
t05: Client: Hi Server, is there an update? 
t06: Server: Yes, here it is!
t07: Client: Hi Server, is there an update?
t08: Server: No
t09: Client: Hi Server, is there an update? 
t10: Server: Yes, here it is!
```

#### Long Polling

```
t01: Client: Hi Server, is there an update?
t06: Server: Yes, here it is!
t07: Client: Hi Server, is there an update?
t10: Server: Yes, here it is!
```

#### Firebase Cloud Messaging

```
t01: Client: Hi Server, I'm client123. Please keep me on track.
t06: Server: Hi client123. There was a change!
t10: Server: Hi client123. There was a change!
```

#### WebSockets

```
t01: Client: Hi Server, here I am. 
t06: Server: There was a change!
t10: Server: There was a change!
```